# Problem with SVN and non-versioned documents not being able to update and clean up

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoise-svn

I am using TortoiseSVN and I am trying to update a folder completely.  However, right-clicking the folder and going "SVN update" doesn't work.  It usually does.  This time it says: `Error Working copy locked. Please execute the 'Cleanup' command.`  Then I did cleanup and it says: `Cleanup failed to process the following paths: In directory x. Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in x  x\y.doc is not under version control.`

I am not sure why I have documents in my svn that is not under version control that some other people put in.  How can I resolve this so that I can go back to my usual right-click, update to just simply update?  Any recommendations are much appreciated! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to update the folder, just delete it with explorer - but not from tortoise menu!

The `svn update` from Tortoise will then restore the folder from svn. Local changes will be lost, however.

Comment: How do you delete it with explorer?

Comment: Simply hit the `DEL` Key.